# I want to insert a piece of javascript code with php values in wordress admin(I tried wp_enque and wp_register)?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I created a very simple plugin in that I need to have a javascript variable.

```
var submit_url = <?php echo "some plugin url from functions"; ?>
```

I don't want to place it in the same view file. I check with both wp_enque and wp_register both of them used only to insert files not piece of script

> please correct me if I am wrong about wp_enque and wp_register

I don't want to place it in the same view file, I checked that I can enter manually in wp-admin/admin-header.php.

Is there any other better way of doing that coz we have not changed anything inside wp-admin so far.

Comment: Hello. What you're trying to do won't work. PHP is Serverside, Javascript Clientside. You can't mix them together as simple as you think. What you need is `AJAX`. With Ajax you can transmitt data between PHP & Javascript.

Comment: :) Thanks for your time. I think, I knew something about that. I asked is there any other better way, if it is AJAX please tell me with some example.